BeginInvoke behavior different in WPF and WinForms
I have an application I am working on in WPF. It uses a serial port connection. I have created a class that wraps the serial port connection and manages buffers, etc.
I developed it when writing a C# WinForms application (.NET6). To allow the serial port events to update a textbox on the main form and send received bytes to a packet handler, I created a delegate and used BeginInvoke to run it. It worked just fine.
I took the same wrapper and included it in a new WPF application, without the textbox updates/packet handler included just to get started (so, only sending bytes out). It also ran fine. I uncommented the receive part of the wrapper, and all still compiles fine (but of course without code on the main form the incoming bytes were not being processed).
When I added the code to the main form to invoke the delegate, I got compile errors. At first, I thought it was a .NET6/.NET8 thing, but I opened the old project and changed the target .NET and it still ran fine.
So, I'm wondering if it's a WinForms vs. WPF thing. The error is:
CS1501  No overload for method 'BeginInvoke' takes 3 arguments
Yet, the exact same code compiles and runs in the old project.
Here is the code in question:
    void ProcessRecievedByte_Callback(object sender, byte rcvdByte)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new ES_UART.RxBufferRemoveByteEventHandler(ES_RxBufferProcessor), sender, rcvdByte);
    }

    void ES_RxBufferProcessor(object sender, byte e)
    {
       switch (receiveState)
        {
            case receive_state.WAITING_FOR_SOP:
                if (e == '$')
                {
                    receiveState = receive_state.IN_A_PACKET;
                    packetIndex = 0;
                    packetBuffer[packetIndex] = e;
                    packetIndex++;
                }
                break;
            case receive_state.IN_A_PACKET:
                if (packetIndex < MAX_PACKET_SIZE)
                {
                    packetBuffer[packetIndex] = e;
                    packetIndex++;
                }
                if (e == '\n')
                    receiveState = receive_state.PACKET_RECIEVED;
                break;
            case receive_state.PACKET_RECIEVED:
                break;
        }
    }


This is how the examples of having a serial port update a text box (or a variable, run a method, etc.) on the UI thread are written. To be fair, most, if not all, of these examples are over 10 years old, and are from WinForms projects. I'm not familiar with iProgress

The examples you mention are over 12 years old, because that's when Task was first introduced. Check Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs. While SerialPort doesn't have any async properties, its BaseStream has asynchronous methods. The code you posted doesn't really need Control.BeginInvoke either, it's trying to process a stream of data in the background. That's possible using eg Dataflow's ActionBlock or Channel.

@PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for that insight - yes, they are over 10 years. I found no other ways to have the serial receive event update the UI thread (text box or variables or run a function) any other way at the time. With a quick scan I haven't found an example of using IProgress<> for serial ports. I'm continuing to look, but if you know of a good reference I'd appreciate it.

Well... bing/copilot created something... :-)

Randomly generated code is worse than 10 year old code that's gone through many modifications. That Rx suggests someone used Rx.NET at some point to buffer bytes into packets but the code was removed, leaving the name. And regressing to pre-C# 3 code. Someone didn't understand what they saw and "fixed" the code by removing essential parts.

Check eg the answers to C# Async Serial Port Read. You can use ReadAsync on BaseStream to read bytes one by one and process them.

The Rx is mine. It has nothing to do with Rx.Net, it is the receive handler for the serial port I'm mostly an embedded guy and develop desktop apps to talk to the embedded system (calibration, testing, data retrieval, etc.) and I started with VB6 around 1998, then C# early on with WinForms, and have recently switched to WPF. RX = receive and TX = transmit on an embedded system. In fact, the "ES" in it means "Em bedded System" so "ES_RxBufferProcessor" means "Embedded System Receive Buffer Processor" and, other than the delegate and invoke strategy, the code is mine.

The packet definition is: $[]\n and each byte is processed individually, hence the state machine looking for '$', the contents and  '\n' to say "Packet Received" for processing. The idea was to create a class, instantiate it, from the form, assign baud rate, number of bits, etc., and then associate a function on the form with the dataReceived even of the serial port. I can reuse the class "as is" in future projects and assign two func for receive and transmit, and all would be good. As I said it works perfectly in WinForms - I need to figure out how to make it work in WPF.

@VinDag I know how serial ports and packets work. I also started in 1996 and even remember the 25-pin ones. And had to work with the @(*&!&%Q FDDI serial USBs in 2004. .NET has a lot of ways to deal with concurrency or processing data streams. I suspect you should check the Dataflow library's blocks that allow you to create a pipeline or mesh of communicating blocks. You could create a block that collects bytes to construct a packet, then passes it to a block that processes the packet. There's no reason to use Control.BeginInvoke and there are no UI controls in background services anyway.

@EmperorEto In my understanding (could be very wrong), when chars are received by the serial port, the DataReceived event is fired (based on the threshold # of char, which I have set to 1). That method cannot call a function on the UI thread or access e.g. textbox1.text properties directly. The idea is to create a delegate (in my embedded world, a pointer) to a function on the UI thread and pass it parameters to work with (in my case, the data byte, and some other info for debugging/monitoring the comm process).

@VinDag btw I started working with VB5 in 1996 too.  Check Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Dataflow Block Type. The Sliding Window example there can be used almost as-is to create packets. Start buffering when you get the start packet, emit when you get the newline. Subsequent blocks will process the packet. Dataflow was actually inspired by embedded systems (more precisely robotics) where dataflow/processing-pipeline architectures are common

@PanagiotisKanavos Sounds like we have had a similar path through our ECE careers. Thanks for the support - I'll look through these resources.

@VinDag If a \n (or \r\n) is the end of a message, you should simply create a StreamReader over the BaseStream of the SerialPort, and call (and await) the StreamReader's ReadLineAsync() method in a loop. It would return each message as a string, and the read loop could be started in the UI thread. There is no need for any BeginInvoke call at all.

@Clemens I don't believe I can do this in a loop because, in this case, it is used for a special tab on my UI that shows comm traffic, and so the UI has to be responsive. If I run it in a loop then the UI would not respond to events until the loop is done (yes, I can construct the equivalent of VB6 DoEvents, but...) and I could do it in a timer to avoid that, but then my response to comms is based on the timer and not on char coming in - I don't like that much for a UI. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

The UI is response with async/await. See the small example in my answer.

@VinDag clemens is correct. When you await an async method while in the UI thread, the UI thread is not blocked, provided the method is well behaved (which this would be). Under the hood the UI thread subscribes to a callback that runs when the awaited action completes, and then continues on immediately. Dispatcher is still used under the hood but it's done transparently; So you can do this in a loop and avoid multi-threading concerns if the result suits your needs. However if you choose instead to directly subscribe to a hardware callback, you do need to use Dispatcher explicitly.

TL;DR - This is simply due to differences between WPF and WinForms. Despite sharing the name BeginInvoke, these methods are not actually the same, but they indeed do effectively the same thing in their respective platforms.
Background
I understand from reading your question that ProcessRecievedByte_Callback will be invoked by the serial port hardware, and thus will execute on a background thread. Further, while you don't show the actual code that updates the TextBox ("without the textbox updates/packet handler included just to get started"), I'm assuming you will in fact be updating the UI in the ES_RxBufferProcessor callback as you say.
Given those assumptions, you indeed do need to use some mechanism to ensure
ES_RxBufferProcessor (or at least the portion of it that updates the UI) is executed on the UI thread. While there are multiple ways to do this, I'll start with the method you ask about - BeginInvoke - before addressing the others.
BeginInvoke
As you probably already know, WinForms and WPF are both single-threaded user interfaces; by design the UI can only be manipulated by code executing on the UI thread. However, there are many times - including when your code is being invoked by a hardware callback - when you find yourself on a background thread but needing to execute code on the UI thread. That's where BeginInvoke and its progeny enter.
WinForm's method - Control.BeginInvoke - and WPF's method - Dispatcher.BeginInvoke - both serve the same purpose in their respective platforms. They are not the exact same method, though, because the means of posting code to a single UI thread is an implementation detail of the platform and not intrinsic to .NET.
Note that there is yet a third BeginInvoke method in .NET Framework that is no longer supported in modern .NET - Delegate.BeginInvoke. This was a means of executing code on a background thread (the opposite of WinForms and WPF's BeginInvoke) and has indeed been obviated by the async/await pattern. This is not what you appear to be trying (or want) to do, but I'm pointing it out for completeness.
In your specific case, if you want to use BeginInvoke to execute on the UI thread, all you have to do is adapt the call slightly to use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke rather than this.BeginInvoke:
    void ProcessRecievedByte_Callback(object sender, byte rcvdByte)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            new ES_UART.RxBufferRemoveByteEventHandler(ES_RxBufferProcessor), 
            sender, 
            rcvdByte);
    }

(Sidenote - I'm assuming you're inside a WPF UserControl here. Consequently, there would be no this.BeginInvoke method available - the method would be this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke, and it would actually have the same method signature as the WinForms variant. I'm not sure exactly why you're getting a CS1501 error without seeing all your code, but as long as you call Dispatcher's BeginInvoke method, the above will work).
And that's basically it. Now code running inside ES_RxBufferProcessor can safely update the UI thread.
The newer approach - InvokeAsync
Before async/await, asynchronous .NET methods often used the BeginXXX and EndXXX pattern. I won't get into all the details as this answer is already too long, but async/await did indeed largely obviate the need for this pattern. The methods aren't deprecated, but they really aren't used much anymore.
Instead, Dispatcher adds InvokeAsync which, among its many overloads, takes an Action and returns an awaitable object so you can wait for the delegate to finish if you want to. If you don't await it, it does the same thing as BeginInvoke except you give it a parameterless lambda/Action instead of a delegate:
    void ProcessRecievedByte_Callback(object sender, byte rcvdByte)
    {
        // Await or not, your choice
        _ = this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            ES_RxBufferProcessor(sender, rcvdByte);
        });
    }

But doesn't async/await eliminate the need for any of this?
Some people mistakenly believe the introduction of async/await removed the need to use the Dispatcher when calling UI code from a worker thread, but this is not the case. What async/await does do is make it simpler to wait for the dispatched code to complete, since async/await is pretty much universally considered superior to the BeginXXX/EndXXX pattern. So again, you could argue the pre-async/await BeginInvoke is obsolete now, and if I were reviewing new code I'd certainly discourage its use in favor of InvokeAsync unless a compelling reason were given.
It's also true that in some cases - maybe even in your specific case - there may be ways to rearchitect the code to avoid finding yourself on a worker thread in the first place, which is what the other answer proposes. This is not always possible, especially when low level hardware is concerned. But if you can rearrange the problem so that you never land on a worker thread, then you indeed don't need to use the Dispatcher. This is because even if you await code that itself runs on a worker thread, as long as you make the call from the UI thread, you will: (a) not block the UI thread while waiting for the async code; and (b) return on the UI thread when the awaited code completes, at which point you can perform any UI updates you need. Under the hood this still in fact uses Dispatcher, but it does so transparently.
Some people may dislike my answer because they believe there is a better approach to your problem all together - and they may well be right - but I'm choosing to answer the question asked (and am fine if others disagree). What is a fact, though, is that if for whatever reason you find your code running on a worker thread and needing to do something on the UI thread, then you need to use the Dispatcher, directly or indirectly.
Progress - The Platform-Agnostic Option
Finally, the comment discussion brought up using IProgress<T> instead of the Dispatcher, but didn't give a clear explanation of how to use it here, so let me finish with that.
IProgress<T> is just a barebones interface for progress reporting. You can't do anything with it on its own - you need to either implement it yourself (which would require you to use the Dispatcher), or use .NET's built-in implementation - Progress<T>.
Here's how you might use it in your case:

Declare an instance of Progress<Action> in a widely-accessible location (perhaps a public static member of App) and - and this part is critical - construct it while on the UI thread. This can be when your application starts. Declare it like this:
public static IProgress<Action> MyDispatcherAbstraction { get; private set; }

(For some reason, Progress<T> implements Report explicitly, so you need the interface, rather than the class instance, to actually use the Report method. Don't ask me why.) Then construct it, possibly in Application.OnStartup:
MyDispatcherAbstraction = new Progress<Action>(action => action()); 

The Action given to the constructor gets executed with the T provided to IProgress<T>.Report. Hence, by making the generic type another Action, you can get it to simply execute whatever code you want and it will do so on the thread on which it was created - which is why you must create it while on the UI thread if you want to use it in place of Dispatcher.

In your ProcessRecievedByte_Callback:
 void ProcessRecievedByte_Callback(object sender, byte rcvdByte)
 {
     MyDispatcherAbstraction.Report(() =>
     {
         ES_RxBufferProcessor(sender, rcvdByte);
     });
 }



Just realize that, under the hood, this actually winds up calling Dispatcher.BeginInvoke anyway. (See DispatcherSynchronizationContext and Progress source). Specifically the IProgress<T>.Report explicit implementation calls the Post method on the synchronization context. So provided you were on the UI thread when it was instantiated, the sync context will be DispatcherSynchronizationContext, and DispatcherSynchronizationContext.Post calls Dispatcher.BeginInvoke. In WPF apps, all paths to the UI run through the Dispatcher one way or another!
Also, FYI, the singleton pattern is fine because the built-in Progress<T> implementation is inherently thread safe, as all it does is invoke the delegate on the thread synchronization context on which the Progress<T> object was instantiated. (See also here). Literally it's the same as what you were trying to do with BeginInvoke, just abstracting away the platform-specific details from you.
So, is Progress<T> better than using Dispatcher.InvokeAsync? Well, the upside is that it's platform agnostic since it's a fundamental .NET type not dependent on WPF. On the other hand, unlike InvokeAsync, IProgress<T>.Report gives you no way to wait for the completion of the delegate before returning. Now in your case, since you were using BeginInvoke anyway, you already didn't really seem to care about this, but it may matter in other cases. But it would be inaccurate to think that it's a replacement for using the Dispatcher in all cases.
As a matter of personal taste, I find the Progress<T> solution to be a little bit of a hack. For a genuine asynchronous progress reporting mechanism it works well enough, but using it to execute arbitrary code on the UI thread on demand isn't exactly its intended purpose. Plus, if you aren't careful to construct it on the UI thread, the entire scheme fails, whereas by using Dispatcher you have no fear of a colleague or future you making such a mistake.
Conclusion
Both WinForms and WPF have dedicated UI threads and thus need, and have, a dispatching mechanism. Neither platform could function without one, and the introduction of async/await does not obviate this need. WPF however offers other newer ways of invoking code on the UI thread, while .NET itself offers a platform-agnostic (but unawaitable) option in the form of Progress<T>.

I am truly sorry for asking a question that caused so much ruckus. And I have no idea why your answer was downvoted 3x before I even read it. In the end, it was the most valuable "short term" answer: To make my code work I just needed to add "Dispatcher." in my existing code. Now that it is working, I can explore/compare/contrast other methods mentioned here. And I've learned a lot. I upvoted the answer, but sadly it's still only -2.

Thanks! And don't worry about it. Let's just say I think there may be some personality conflicts at play. :) You're welcome to accept either answer if you see fit. Or if anything is unclear or you have follow up q's please fire away. Cheers.

You do not need any BeginInvoke call. Just create a StremReader over the BaseStream of the SerialPort and call and await the ReadLineAsync method in a loop.
Here is a small example that reads NMEA messages from a GPS device on a virtual COM port and shows them in a TextBlock (declared in XAML):
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += OnWindowLoaded;
}

public async void OnWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    using var port = new SerialPort("COM6", 9600);
    port.Open();

    using var reader = new StreamReader(port.BaseStream);

    string message;

    while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message = await reader.ReadLineAsync()))
    {
        textBlock.Text = message;
    }
}


According to the code posted in the question, he's processing byte by byte, so a simple Stream.ReadAsync would seem to make more sense than a StreamReader.

OP is processing input byte by byte to get the message start and end characters $ and \n - but just because they don't have the necessary buffering to read entire strings. Their goal is to get the messages - which are strings in the format  $<cmd>[<parameter>]\n - similar to NMEA messages.

And that may be so, but you've reframed the whole problem from one about how to run code on the UI thread from a worker-thread callback to one about how to read NMEA messages on a serial port.  This might or might not be helpful to VinDag but it doesn't help readers looking for info about BeginInvoke.

@EmperorEto This answer solves the original problem of the OP. It provides a graceful alternative to his original approach. OP was only asking about BeginInvoke because his code was not behaving as expected. He was not looking for a lesson about BeginInvoke for academic reasons. Now he found a better solution that also completely avoids BeginInvoke.
